# awk compare two columns in two files print result

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to match each lines `$2` in `f1` and `f2` and then `$1` in `f1` and `f2`, and if both match the `$3` is "MATCH" otherwise `$3` is "MISMATCH". The `awk` below produces does not execute unless I remove one of the `if` statements. Thank you :).

**f1**

```
1234 aaa
5678 xxxx
1244 yyyy
2255 zzzz
```

**f2**

```
5678 xxxx
224 zzzz
1244 yyyy
1234 aaa
```

**desired**

```
1234 aaa MATCH
5678 xxxx MATCH
1244 yyyy MATCH
2255 zzzz MISMATCH
```

**awk**

```
awk 'if($2==$2) && if($1==$1){print $3,"MATCH"} else {print $3,"MISMATCH"}}' f1 f2
```

Comment: if statements should be contained within the same set of parentheses: `if($2==$2 && $1==$1)`

Comment: yes, but how would `awk` know how to differentiate a `$1` from `f1`, vs a `$1` from `f2`? . `$2==$2` will **always** be true, because you're comparing the same field that contains the same data. Good answer below. Good luck to all.

Comment: is there a particular reason why you want to compare fields instead of entire line between the two files? wouldn't `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {$3 = ($0 in a) ? "MATCH" : "MISMATCH"} 1' f2 f1` solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK doesn't read input files simultaneously.
First you need to read `f2` into an array, then you can use the array to determine what will be in `$3` while processing `f1`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$3=(($1 in a&&a[$1]==$2)?"":"MIS")"MATCH"} 1' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(This will print those values which are present in file1 and not in file2 for NON-MATCH keyword printing).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$0
  next
}
{
  print $0,$1 in a?"MATCH":"NON-MATCH"
}'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

---

---

***Additional solution:*** If you want to print non-matching lines for both files(since above code prints only those which are in file1 and NOT in file2).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  print $0,$1 in a?"MATCH":"NON-MATCH-FILE1"
  b[$1 in a?$1:""]
}
END{
  for(i in a){
     if(!(i in b)){
        print a[i]" NON-MATCH-FILE2"
     }
  }
}'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Comment: Thank you both :).